# FFmpeg - Transcode video and keep original EXIF metadata in the transcoded file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata, transcode

I am trying to transcode a video from a .mov (recorded with the iPhone) and add the original metadata (EXIF) to transcoded file, how can I achieve that? The original video contains EXIF metadata, etc.

Here is what I have tried but it does not add the metadata:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -map 0 -vcodec libx264 -preset superfast -acodec libfaac output.mp4

ffmpeg -i input.mov -map_metadata 0  -vcodec libx264 -preset superfast -acodec libfaac output.mp4
```

Comment: ffmpeg keeps all metadata by default _if_ the target container can handle it. Btw. [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) is for images (Exchangeable image file format).

Comment: Yes, you are right about the EXIF. The videos have metadata that contains location was my point and I'd like to keep it in the new format. Does it mean that mp4 format cannot handle it?

Comment: mp4-Tags (from the [AtomicParsley](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/) help function: [here](http://ramit.in/657bec2ff0_nl.html))